# OpenLayers 4 getFeatures

Tags: javascript, openlayers, xml

I've implemented the getFeature function in my OL4 as in the example:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-tile.html

```
  map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
    var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
    var url = wmsSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
        evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
        {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});
    if (url) {
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
          '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
    }
  });
```

How can I handle the result in order to create a tooltip? I don't want to use the `<iframe>`

If I console.log the var URL, I have back the URL itself and not the XML page, how can I have back the XML page?

I also tried with `var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(url,"text/xml");` but what I get back is not the XML.

Comment: You can use `Overlay` as an HTMLElement. and just check the comments on your past question. that's the answer how you do.

Comment: I answer you in the other post, in this post we are talking about different stuff, if you click on the street line in this web http://www.traffwebdemo.co.uk/parking/ you have back data from mapserver, and it's manipulated to appear in the popup.

Comment: the comment is for your first question about iframe.

Comment: As I don't want the iframe and I don't know how to use the `Overlay `I found a way with `XMLHttpRequest()` you can see the solution below in my answer. It seems that OL4 doesn't create a real xml request, it gives you an URL and with `iframe` you can access that URL and import the content, but I want to manipulate the content before to show it on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way.

```
if (url) {

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.send();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4) {
    if (xhttp.status == 200)  {
      //console.log(xhttp.responseText);
      document.getElementById('popup-content').innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    };

} // end if url
```